# Possible design strategies for login for multi-tenant cloud application?

Tags: authentication, cloud, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi-tenant cloud application and considering using E-mail addresses/passwords for general login credentials.  However,  I may have the same user (same E-mail address) associated with multiple tenants based on the planned sales model for this application. For example, multiple departments in the same company might be separate tenants, or separate companies must be separate tenants.  In either case the same user (with same E-mail address) might be a user of these different tenants.

What are possible design strategies for handling such situation?

One approach I am considering is separating creation and update of the user E-mail credentials from the tenants.  In this approach a tenant could invite a user (by sending an E-mail) and the user can use the same login credentials for access to all tenants, merely switching between tenants as desired.

What I have typically seen in current web applications is that the user has to have separate E-mail addresses for each tenants, which seems a burden for the user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your question is about the technical design (and not the user experience), this is a pretty straight forward solution.  Create the users independently from the tenants, and allow for a many to many relationship that represents the "has access to" phrase.

Depending on your chosen backend, there are different manifestations of the design pattern:

1. RDBMS: Create a user table, tenant table and a user_has_access_to relationship table
2. Directory Server (LDAP): Place the users into a single OU within the directory, and create the tenants as group objects.  The users could then have the memberOf attribute set for each tenant they are able to access.

The LDAP option above has the limitation of overloading the group entity.  If you are comfortable enough with LDAP schema definitions, you could just as easily create a tenant object and add a hasAccessToTenant attribute to your user object. Taking this approach would allow you to use groups to represent actual user groups (as the object type was intended to be used).

A more advanced design option would include the creation of a "has access to" relationship between tenants.  Adding this, along with the user to tenant relationship, would open up more advanced relationship modeling.  For example:  a tenant with departments or divisions, allowing users with permission to the top level tenant to automatically "have access to" the divisions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same credential across namespaces in multi-tenant applications is technically possible. For example, when a user logs in, the application can check across the namespaces and determine which all namespaces he belongs to. There is a possibility, the user may have different levels of authorizations against these namespaces. This is also implementable.

The real problem is the experience the application can offer to such users. They will require a special landing page which will allow them to chose between the namespaces. The chosen namespace should be made quasi-permanent during the session, that is,  until the user logs out. ( I am trying to implement this in a new application on GAE/Python27 )

Other possibilities are restricting the user to a single namespace and asking the user to use different credentials against each namespace, which seems to be the prevailing practice.